# How to pass an argument to functions mapped using ...mapActions(...)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Considering the following passage

```
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["updateData", "resetData"]);
  }
}
```

I'd like to pass in a parameter into the called functions. Not certain how to do so properly while still retaining the `...mapAction()` call, I had to rewrite to the following.

```
export default {
  methods: {
    // ...mapActions(["updateData", "resetData"])
    updateData: function() { this.$store.dispatch("updateData", "names") },
    resetData: function() { this.$store.dispatch("resetData"); }
  }
}
```

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just pass the parameter to the method, where you are calling it. you can only send one parameter, which will be available in the actions. You don't have to do anything special when using `mapActions`

For example you can call it like:

```
<button @click=updateData({data1: 1, data2: 2})>
```

and in the vuex store:

```
const actions = {
  updateData: (state, data) => {
     //You will get passed parameter as data here
  },
```

and you can still use mapActions:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["updateData", "resetData"]);
  }
}
```

see working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zh64b41m/2/): you can see passed parameter in the alert :)

---

Here is the implementation of `mapActions` from [vuex repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/2a67103a1f5fc1448a694e7f83a5f0c6d6bc8262/src/helpers.js#L36)

```
export function mapActions (actions) {
  const res = {}
  normalizeMap(actions).forEach(({ key, val }) => {
    res[key] = function mappedAction (...args) {
      return this.$store.dispatch.apply(this.$store, [val].concat(args))
    }
  })
  return res
}
```

You can see it takes the `args` passed and puts them as a second argument of dispatch function.